# eclipse auto complete malfunction or op. error

Tags: java, eclipse

so I just downloaded eclipse and it came with a basic hello world program, and the auto complete works on this. It will work with the auto trigger "." and by using ctrl+space, and it shows all the suggestions you would expect. When I started my own project though, the auto correct must be called to work and there are not any suggestions in the auto complete drop down box. Does anyone know what could cause this????

Comment: can you give an concrete example where the autocomplete drop down box is blank? What did you type? What do you expect to be in the drop down box?

Answer (score 0):

2 things come to mind.

1) make sure setting in the preferences page under Java -> editor -> Content Assist is enabled. and that the delay is short.

2) check your build libraries and path are correct.  it may be having trouble finding any methods that you can use.